# How to read sub directories file name in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to read files names from the directories which starts with 2016. The output  should be created to another files.

For example, I have directory /bishare/DLSFTP/ in this I have 2016-06, 2016-06, and 2016-07.

All the directories having sub directory as well.

I need 3 output file which will be having the details of directory starts with 2016.

**Edit:**

Initially I wrote the below script:

```
 #!/bin/bash CURRENT_DATE=date +'%d%m%Y' File_Path=/bishare/DLSFTP/2016-06 cd /appinfprd/biIA83/Client/Scripts/IRP/ cd cd $File_Path for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do echo -n $i": " ; 
File_Data=find $i type f |ls -R printf '%s\n' "$D" "|" "$File_Data" /n>> /appinfprd/biIA83/Client/Scripts/IRP/Bishare_File_Data_$CURR‌​ENT_DATE.txt done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use find command with exec param and ls command as below;

```
find . -name "2016*" -type d -exec bash -c 'ls "{}"> "{}".txt ' \;
```

ls output is written `<directoryName>.txt`

To find all directories which starts with 2016 as below and type -d are found only directory;

```
find . -name "2016*" -type d
```

To perform ls for each of directories and write outputs to folderName.txt files

```
-exec bash -c 'ls "{}"> "{}".txt ' \;
```

Comment: ,could you please explain me the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`find` needs a starting point, and the .(dot) is selecting the current directory. E.g. if you're in /home/myuser, find /home/myuser and find . have the same result

```
  find . -name "2016*"
```